# Android GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this) returning null on google play service version 9.0.83

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-sdk-2.3

I am facing an issue with GooglePlayServiceUtil, with some devices which is having google play service installed with 9.0.83. 
I have checked the same in device having play service version 8.7.03 and I am getting the legal notice.

Below is the code I have used to get the legal notice.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notice);
if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ConnectionResult.SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tv.setText(GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this));
}else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING){
        Toast.makeText(this, "ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this)
```

is returning null for version 9.0.83. But it is returning the legal notice string for verion 8.7.03 and 7.x.x devices.

I have also tried with

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(Context)
```

but the result is same as GooglePlayServicesUtil. 
It would be helpful, if anyone can guide me on this to get the proper result.

Comment: I think a lot of programmers are experiencing the same error as you did. Like this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273810/getopensourcesoftwarelicenseinfo-is-returning-null-now) and they have already filed a bug report. Kindly follow this link to be updated on any progress regarding the [report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9806)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after upgrading Google Play Services (9.0.0 at time of writing this answer), rebuilding the project and reinstalling the app, I started getting the licenses properly.

I'm using `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this);`